# Erlang ETS Match

Tags: erlang, match, ets

with Erlang ets, how can Match part of key?

for exmaple,`ets:insert(time_tb,{ {un_known,{<<"knonw_1">>,<<"knonw_2">>} },[data]}).`

the key was `{un_known,{<<"knonw_1">>,<<"knonw_2">>}`

How can I match from the table if I only knows `{<<"knonw_1">>,<<"knonw_2">>}` is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly,no necessary use function match. You can do this with functions [ets:select](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select-2) and [est:fun2ms](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#fun2ms-1) for simplify match specifications.

```
R=ets:fun2ms(fun(Data={{_,T},_}) when T =:= {<<"knonw_1">>,<<"knonw_2">>}->Data end).
ets:select(time_tb,R).
```

and get:

```
[{{un_known,{<<"knonw_1">>,<<"knonw_2">>}},[data]}]
```